# Most efficient design for item's price based on day of week and time

Tags: database-design

Here is the scenario: 
I'm trying to create a website that will allow a store to enter a product and price. I want them to be able to set different prices based on different days of the week and time of day. A user could then go to the website, select the store and item, and it would return the current price.

Original thought:
On the form I would have the form allow for regular price and sale price, and each day they could select a sale begin time and end time if they want. This would be minimal on the database side, but is very rigid and doesn't allow much flexibility(no more than one sale price in a day for multiple time points).

If I add more time points and prices will that dramatically slow down the queries? Is it best to put all of these point into one table or would it be more efficient to break them into separate tables? Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it best to put all of these point into one table or would it be more efficient to break them into separate tables?

It's always more efficient to [normalize your data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

> If I add more time points and prices will that dramatically slow down the queries?

It depends on what kind of database you use.  Relational databases were designed for normalized data.

For items with many prices, here's how you would model the data.

```
Item
----
Item ID
Item Name
Price
...


ItemPrice
---------
ItemPrice ID
Item ID
Price
From Time Stamp
To Time Stamp
```

The ID field in the first column of the tables is a primary clustering key, an auto-incrementing int or long.

In the `Item` table, the price is the usual price.

In the `ItemPrice` table, you also have a unique index on (Item ID, From Time Stamp descending).  The from time stamp and the to time stamp would define the dates and times of the changed prices.

So, every time you look up a price in your website application code, you check the `ItemPrice` table first.  If you don't get a changed price row, you use the price in the `Item` table.

You also have to make sure in your website application code that there's only one changed price for a given date / time range.

A from time stamp and to time stamp work when you want to change prices every so often, like monthly.  If you want to have regular Sunday price changes, you'd need a [calendar table](http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables) too, so your website application can generate the time stamps from the calendar.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning what a good index would be to optimize lookup of the currently applicable changed price for an item. Probably `ItemPrice (ItemID, ToTime)`? It would be nice to optimize the WHERE conditions for both `FromTime` and `ToTime`, but as far as I know, RDBMSs cannot benefit from indexes on 2 different range conditions for the same query. There should also be a `LIMIT 1` on this query so the RDBMS can return as soon as it finds a matching row.

Comment: @Alex D: I corrected the ItemPrice index.  You could also include the To Time Stamp as a part of the index, but I'm not sure that improves performance enough.  You don't want to put a limit on the query.  You want to flag an error if you return more than one row for a given date / time.

Comment: I thought about it, and I think `(ItemID, ToTime)` is likely to perform a lot better than `(ItemID, FromTime)`. The condition will be `WHERE FromTime <= NOW() AND ToTime >= NOW()`. As more and more records accumulate in the DB, the number of matching records for the `FromTime` clause will increase. But the number of records matching the `ToTime` clause will probably always be small (unless "changed prices" are saved for dates far in the future). Unless, that is, out-of-date "changed prices" are deleted from the DB... in that case `FromTime` would be better.

Comment: @Alex D: You're correct.  That's why I said from time stamp **descending**.  The database engine stops returning rows when the to time stamp < now.  Of course, the exact methodology depends on which database SQL engine we're talking about.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for your detailed answer! I never thought about having each different item at different prices as being an unique item in the tables. One more question. Do you think I need the two tables? Would it be better to have all of them in the ItemPrice example and I could calculate the totime and from time based on when there specials are?

Comment: @badger0053: Yes, you need the two tables I outlined.  Do not combine them into one table.  Your website application code is responsible for getting the one price.